# Libsodium and Perfect Forward Secrecy

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, nonce, libsodium

I'm thinking of creating a mobile app that uses Libsodium's `crypto_box_easy`for encrypting and decrypting chat messages.

However, after reading a lot on the net, I found that one of the major flaws of public-private-key algorithms is that recorded data can be decrypted as soon as the recipients private key is leaked.

To avoid that, the use of Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS) is suggested and I'm wondering, if Libsodium is already supporting PFS in the former mentioned function as individual `nonces` are used for each encryption.

Maybe someone can guide me on the difference between PFS and Libsodiums functions (if there are some) or help me by clarifying the relationship of nonces and PFS.

Comment: Migh look at https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/key_exchange and note that Perfect Forward Secrecy =  Forward Secrecy

Comment: Whilst there may not be implicit forward secrecy, you can use ephemeral/ephemeral crypto_box keypairs to achieve forward secrecy in libsodium, You simply need to generate new shared secrets based off of ephemeral keyPairs per session.

Answer (score 0):

There is no forward secrecy.

`crypto_box_seal()` is slightly better, as the sender uses ephemeral keys. These messages can be signed using a long-term secret key in order to check that they come from the expected party, but that key being compromised will not allow decryption of previous messages.

However, if the recipient's secret key get compromised, recorded messages can still be decrypted.

For these reasons, the `box` construction doesn't exist in [libhydrogen](https://libhydrogen.org). Instead, there are [Noise](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/)-based protocol implementations for secure key exchange, all with forward secrecy. These APIs will be backported to libsodium at some point.

But secure chat applications are far from trivial to build. The [signal](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c) library is a much better starting point, even though the license may not be compatible with your expectations.